# Patron modular JS no funciona en Edge

Tags: javascript, patrones-de-diseño, modular

Estoy en un desarrollo al cual le apliqué el patrón modular de Javascript para tener el código mas prolijo y escalable y estoy teniendo problemas con MS Edge. En Chrome y Firefox anda perfecto. Paso una parte del código:

HTML

```js
let globals={base_url: "..."};

var Garantia = (function () {
            
            var url = {
              validarCapitalGarantizado: globals.base_url+"/validarCapitalGarantizado",
              getCuit : globals.base_url+"/obtenerGarantiasPorCUITyEfi/"
            }
        
            var elements = {
                selectDestino: $("#select-destino"),
                selectSistema: $("#select-sistema"),
                selectFecuencia: $("#select-frecuencia-amortizacion"),
                selectOperacion: $("#tipo-operacion"),
                tasaInteres: $('#tasa-interes'),
                plazoTotal: $("#plazo-total"),
                cuit: $('#cuit'),
                efi: $('#efi'),
                form: $('form'),
                montoGarantizado: $('#monto-garantizado'),
                montoTotal: $('#monto-total'),
                fechaAcreditacion: $("#fecha-acreditacion"),
                tipoOperacion: $("#tipo-operacion"),
                garantiasVinculadas: $('#garantias-vinculadas'),
                optionRefinanciacion: $("#tipo-operacion [value= 'r']")
            }
        
            var hiddenElements = {
                montoMaximo: $('#montoMaximo'),
                garantiasActuales: $('#garantiasActuales'),
                montoMaximoGarantias: $('#maxGarantias')
            }
        
            //----- Private Methods --------
            var suscribeEvents = function(){
        
                elements.form.on('submit', events.submit);
                elements.montoGarantizado.on('change', events.validarMontos);
                elements.montoTotal.on('change', events.validarMontos);
                elements.cuit.on('change', events.getMontosMaximos);
                elements.cuit.on('change', events.cargarGarantiasCuit);
                elements.fechaAcreditacion.on('change', events.validarAcreditacionYPlazo);
                elements.plazoTotal.on('change', events.validarAcreditacionYPlazo);
                elements.tipoOperacion.on('change',events.toggleRefinanciacion);
            };
        
            var events = {
    submit: function(e) {
                if (!validaciones()){
                    return false;         
                } 
                elements.form.submit();
            },
            validarMontos: function(e){
                calculoPorcentajeYGarantizado();
            },
            getMontosMaximos:function(e){
                getMontosMaximos();
            },
            validarAcreditacionYPlazo: function(e){
                validarAcreditacionYPlazo(e);
            },
            toggleRefinanciacion: function(e){
                if (elements.tipoOperacion.val() == 'r') {
                   elements.garantiasVinculadas.prop('disabled',false);
                } else {
                   elements.garantiasVinculadas.prop('disabled',true);
                }
            },
            cargarGarantiasCuit: function(e){
                cargarGarantiasCuit();
            }
            };
        
            //carga los id de garantias vinculadas al cuit en el select.
            var cargarGarantiasCuit = function(){
        
            }
        
            var validarAcreditacionYPlazo = function(e){
                
            }
        
            var calculoPorcentajeYGarantizado = function(){
               
            }
        
            //validaciones de frmulario
            var validaciones = function(){
                return true;
            }
        
            var getMontosMaximos = function(){
        
            }
        
            var getPriceAsFloat = function(id){
            }
        
            //----- Public methods --------
            //inicializa el objeto
            var initialize = function(e){
                suscribeEvents();
                elements.optionRefinanciacion.prop('disabled',true);
                elements.garantiasVinculadas.prop('disabled',true)
            }
        
            //----- Public API --------
              return {
                init: initialize,
                getMontosMaximos: getMontosMaximos,
                validaciones: validaciones
              }
        }());
        
        Garantia.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cuit">CUIT</label>
    <input class="form-control"
    type="text"
    name="cuit"
    id="cuit"
    required>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- -->
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fecha-acreditacion">Fecha de acreditación del préstamo:</label>
    <input class="form-control calendar"
    type="text"
    name="fechaAcreditacionPrestamo"
    id="fecha-acreditacion"
    >
  </div>
</div>
<!-- -->
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fecha-primer-vencimiento">Fecha del primer vencimiento:</label>
    <input class="form-control calendar"
    type="text"
    name="fechaPrimerVencimiento"
    id="fecha-primer-vencimiento"
    placeholder="Primer vencimiento de amortización del capital"
    >
  </div>
</div>
<!-- -->
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="monto-total">Monto total prestamo:</label>
    <input class="form-control price"
    type="text"
    name="montoTotalCredito"
    id="monto-total"
    required >
  </div>
</div>
<!-- -->
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="monto-garantizado">Monto Garantizado:</label>
    <input class="form-control price"
    type="text"
    name="montoGarantizado"
    id="monto-garantizado"
    required >
  </div>
</div>
<!-- -->
```

El "Objeto" de JS que interacciona con esa parte del HTML:

No puse los cuerpos de los metodos porque son largos. En fin, en Edge pongo Breakpoints dentro de los metodos y nunca llega (Si se ejecuta el Init y el suscribeEvents). Es decir, el evento no se esta asociando a los elementos. Alguna idea de que puede ser?

PD: En la consola no aparecen errores de sintaxis. Esto esta funcionando en Chrome, es algo que Edge no soporte?

Comment: ¿El método init no se llega a ejecutar?

Comment: Veo varios errores de sintaxis, cada declaración de variable  dentro de la función autoejecutable deberían culminar con **punto y coma**.

Comment: @PabloLozano Si, se ejecuta!

Comment: @Blasito la consola no tiene errores de sintaxis. No se a que referís con la funcion autoejecutable, pero las variables se declaran como objeto..

Comment: @Blasito Aunque es muy recomendable añadirlos, los puntos y coma en JS son opcionales

Comment: @PabloLozano entiendo, pero me sigue pareciendo un error de sintaxis. Fijate como termina el código antes de la llamada al init: `}());`, ¿no debería terminar así `})();`?

Comment: Agregué el contenido de events (lo borré sin querer). Alguna idea de por qué en MsEdge podría no funcionar?